# How do you access url args in react-router-dom 4 when using Route render prop instead of Route component prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router-dom v 4.0.0.

In my top-level `<App />` component that renders my react router, I have three routes.  The first two work as expected, the third one does not.

```
render() {
    const pageMain = (
        <PageMain token={this.state.token} />
    );
    const pageActivity = (
        <PageActivity
            projectActivities={this.state.projectActivities}
            projectActivitiesMap={this.state.projectActivitiesMap} />
    );
    return (<Router>
        <div>
            <Route
                path="/"
                component={PageSplash}
            />
            <Route
                path="/app"
                render={props => pageMain}
            />
            <Route
                path="/activity/:activityId/"
                render={props => pageActivity}
            />
        </div>
    </Router>);
}
```

When I go to **www.example.com/**, the router directs me to my PageSplash component as expected.

When I go to **www.example.com/app**, the router directs me to my PageMain component as expected.  Further, in my PageMain component, I have access to `this.props.token` as expected.

When I go to **www.example.com/activity/12345/**, the router directs me to my PageActivity component as expected.  In my PageActivity component, I have access to `this.props.projectActivities` and `this.props.projectActivitiesMap` as expected.  However, I'd like to be able to access the activityId from the url, which should be 12345 in this case.  In PageActivity, I don't receive `this.props.params` as I thought, from reading countless pages of documentation.

I started by using simple routes like my first one.  Then I needed to pass data from my top-level component to the /app route, so I begin using the `<Route />` `render` prop instead of the `component` prop.  This works fine.  Then I needed to pass data and access the url param.  I can access the passed props, but my PageActivity component isn't receiving a params prop.  How do I access the activityId in my PageActivity component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.  I needed to inline my PageActivity component, and add `{...props}`.  The problematic route looks like this now:

```
<Route path="/activity/:activityId/" render={props => (
    <PageActivity
        projectActivities={this.state.projectActivities}
        projectActivitiesMap={this.state.projectActivitiesMap}
        {...props}
    />
)} />
```

Also, in react-router-dom 4.0.0, page params are passed in `this.props.match.params`.